# Symfony 4.4 Error on FOSUserBundle Installation

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-4.4

I followed this two post about "how to install fosuserbundle in symfony 4.4":

https://vfac.fr/blog/how-install-fosuserbundle-with-symfony-4

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/794/how-to-install-and-configure-fosuserbundle-in-symfony-4

But at the end i got this error:

> Argument 3 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
> given, called in /url/to/symfony/proyect/var/cache/dev/ContainerKx7xY28/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1466

[image]
i didn't change anything about FOSUserBundle but it's seems that something is wrong in my configuration...

My config files are these:

security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        #users_in_memory: { memory: null }
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            #anonymous: lazy
            #provider: users_in_memory
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

packages/fos_user.yaml

```
# config/packages/fos_user.yaml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "email@email.com"
        sender_name: "email@email.com"
```

src/Entity/User.php

```
<?php
// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just tried the same guide with symfony 4.3 and it's work! so i think is something about compability of symfony 4.4 and FOSUserBundle...

Comment: Please share more details, like the **exact** package versions you are using, especially from `doctrine/*`, for both the version working with Symfony 4.3 and the non-working example with Symfony 4.4. This could help to find the incompatibilitiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem related to the fos user bundle, but with your declaration of user.

Read [this post first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678333/construct-must-be-an-instance-of-doctrine-common-persistance-objectmanager).

See your User declaration :

```
<?php
// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager; <---
```

Try replace it with

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface; <---
```

You may have somewhere in your code where you use an entity object which is declared with ObjectManager instead of EntityManagerInterface.

Please if this is not working explain why you add this line :

```
// Añadimos esta linea porque parece que hacer algo...
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
```

**EDIT**

Ok I've been looking for it, and that's look like a bug with doctrine.
I found this issue : https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8242.

It solve your problem.

Just update your composer.json like :

```
...
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/common":"^2.13", <------
...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi!

Sorry i forgot delete this line! it's useless(Edited in original post)

i did all in a new proyect so i didn't use my EntityManager in any place,
and i still get the same error in symfony 4.4 but when i tried in the 4.3 with the
same config and same entity i got no errors.

if u want to see the proyect just check it: https://github.com/Franrredo/demoTest

Comment: Ok, Symfony 4.3 is not maintain anymore, so you should'nt use it. So you want to use Symfony 4.4 and that's correct as it is a long term version. But may I ask why you don't create this with the new version of Symfony (like 5.1) ?

Comment: Thx 4 all, it solve the problem!!!!!
Btw i'm using the 4.4 because is the current lts! When 5.x get the lts i'll upgrade the proyect.

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot on internet finding the best solution and there was not one solved my problem, so I saw the services that uses the bundle and see that `fos_user.user_manager.default`: service is the one who call the `Doctrine\Modle\UserManager` so I rewrite it with my own class

```
fos_user.user_manager.default:
        class: App\Model\UserManager
        arguments:
            - '@fos_user.util.password_updater'
            - '@fos_user.util.canonical_fields_updater'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
            - '%fos_user.model.user.class%'
```

1. Create your own class to manage your `fosUser` entity, it has to extends of `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager` (can copy the code of the same class)
2. Rewrite the service injecting the same parameters, except the third parameter, it will be replaced by `EntityManagerInterface`

I hope that will help you, It worked for me.

Comment: This is great, using configuration as a workaround is a perfect solution vs having to lock your Doctrine dependency to an outdated version.